# Python logging with context - Passing key

Tags: python, logging, aop

I am fairly new to Python. I have been modifying our existing python modules for improved logging. I came across with a requirement to tag each method call(and exit) with a specific key (context) that needs to be logged and entry and exit points. That key is supposed to be generated at root method and passed down to further method calls.

I am confused over the approach I should follow. Is there a way to dynamically insert an extra parameter in existing method interface may be using AOP or annotations ?

Or I rephrase this question to short -

**How can I pass an extra argument to subsequent method calls ?**

Thanks
Panks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single logger instance for all those methods, maybe you could have the root method set the context on the logger on entry and remove it on exit.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def setup_login(logger, context):
    old_name = logger.name
    logger.name = context
    yield
    logger.name = old_name
```

And the root method becomes :

```
def root():
    context = compute_context()
    with setup_login(logger, context):
        # call other methods
```

I used `logger.name`, but you could use any other attribute of logger, or use any other singleton to share the global state.

Comment: Thanks Madjar. I have single logger but each time a method is called by a different thread, it should create a new context. So I think I can't rely on logger attributes. If I could overload selected methods at runtime and add extra parameter, I could define my context key in logger formatter and log the context key. Just a thought.

Comment: Indeed, this won't work in multithreaded environment, except if you use thread-local globals (glocals). The problem with adding an extra parameter is I can't think of an easy way to add it to the call of a method without modifying the code calling the method. Another way to do (but it's getting more and more hacking) would be to use `inspect` and go up the stack until you find the context key.